# C++ error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[63]’ to ‘char*’ in initialization

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char, char-pointer

I seem to be more of a noob in C++ than I originally thought. As far as my knowledge of C/C++ goes, this should work. I define a character array then try to assign a pointer to the beginning... What am I doing wrong?

```
// Create character array
char str[] = "t xtd 02 1CF00400 08 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 0   0 1234.567890";
// Assign pointer to beginning of array
char* p = &str;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of `str` is `char[63]`. For reference, note that the type of the string literal itself is `const char[63]`, not `const char *`. You take the address of that, which gives you a pointer to `char[63]`, or `char (*)[63]`. You then try to assign that to a `char *`.

What you should do is not take the address and let the array decay into a pointer:

```
char *p = str;
```

What you should really do, though, is use `std::string`.

Comment: Your answer is well defined, but can you help me understand a little more? Are you saying that my char array is made into a constant?

Comment: @EricFossum, It takes the literal, which is an array of constant characters, **copies** them into an array of non-constant chars (which is ok because they're copied), which you then use with your pointer. I felt the need to explicitly say that the literal isn't a pointer, it's an array, as so many people don't know that (as I've seen from 10k+ rep people giving wrong answers when that question was asked a few months ago).

Answer (score 5):

You can simply omit the address operator,

```
char *p = str;
```

works, arrays automatically decay into pointers to the first element in that context. Or, if you wish, explicitly cast, but that would be an abomination.

Answer (score 1):

```
 char* p = str;
```

The ampersand is redundant. A plain array name just denotes an address of it's beginning.